# Python kernel continually crashes when executing a cell

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

I'm working on applying a clustering algorithm (sklearn.AgglomerativeClustering) on a dataset. I've tried running this same block of code in Spyder IDE and VScode, each time the cell runs for about 35-45s then returns a message that the kernel crashed unexpectedly and and new kernel is created. Im using Python 3.10 with Anaconda package manager.

Spyder had no information about the kernel crash but in VScode I was pointed to this github post [Kernel-crashes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Kernel-crashes). I figured somehow my numpy installation was affecting kernel performance or execution. I created a new virtual env using conda; re-installed numpy, pandas, sci-kit learn, etc. Same kernel crash occurring with the same message.

I am using a new Macbook with the m1 chip. Unsure if that's has an influence or is a hint at how to solve this issue. Did see the sci-kit learn installation docs had separate section [sci-kit learn install docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#install-official-release) about installing with m1 chip but to be honest wasn't exactly sure how to interpret and use that info.

this is the code Im trying to run that causes the kernel to crash. the `pca_features` is the numpy array return after running `.fit_transform` method on my raw data. PCA executed fine for what it's worth and showed no issues. Tried using subset of rows, first 5000, to see if that helped cell run at all but still no luck.

Error Message:
**The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Kernel-crashes) for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done**

Im open to other clustering algorithms but fact that I can't get this to execute makes me less confident any others (e.g. KMeans) would successfully run. But I could be wrong.

My goal is get a unsupervised clustering algorithm fitted to the data so I can get labels for each observation and compare it against primary components from PCA.

````
```
aggclus = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 4, affinity="euclidean",linkage="ward") 
subset_pcafeatures = pca_features[:5000,5]
cluster_labels = aggclus.fit_predict(pca_features)
```
````

Any tips/advice/help/assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you

**Updated 29-01-23**

- output from `$ conda list`

```bash
# packages in environment at ../anaconda3/envs/work-env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blas                      2.116                  openblas    conda-forge
blas-devel                3.9.0           16_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.3.5           py310h96f19d2_0  
brotli                    1.0.9                h1a28f6b_7  
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h1a28f6b_7  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h620ffc9_4  
ca-certificates           2023.01.10           hca03da5_0  
certifi                   2022.12.7       py310hca03da5_0  
comm                      0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.0.5           py310h525c30c_0  
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
debugpy                   1.5.1           py310hc377ac9_0  
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fftw                      3.3.9                h1a28f6b_1  
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
freetype                  2.12.1               h1192e45_0  
giflib                    5.2.1                h80987f9_1  
ipykernel                 6.20.2             pyh736e0ef_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.8.0              pyhd1c38e8_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.1.1           py310hca03da5_0  
jpeg                      9e                   h1a28f6b_0  
jupyter_client            7.4.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.1.1           py310hca03da5_0  
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py310h313beb8_0  
lcms2                     2.12                 hba8e193_0  
lerc                      3.0                  hc377ac9_0  
libblas                   3.9.0           16_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h1a28f6b_7  
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h1a28f6b_7  
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h1a28f6b_7  
libcblas                  3.9.0           16_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libcxx                    14.0.6               h848a8c0_0  
libdeflate                1.8                  h1a28f6b_5  
libffi                    3.4.2                hca03da5_6  
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_3_0_hca03da5_28  
libgfortran5              11.3.0              h009349e_28  
liblapack                 3.9.0           16_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
liblapacke                3.9.0           16_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.21          openmp_hc731615_3    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hb8d0fd4_0  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.0                h2fd578a_0  
libwebp                   1.2.4                h68602c7_0  
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h1a28f6b_0  
llvm-openmp               14.0.6               hc6e5704_0  
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h313beb8_0  
matplotlib                3.6.2           py310hca03da5_0  
matplotlib-base           3.6.2           py310h8bbb115_0  
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
missingno                 0.4.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  h313beb8_0  
nest-asyncio              1.5.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.8.4           py310hecc3335_0  
numpy                     1.23.5          py310hb93e574_0  
numpy-base                1.23.5          py310haf87e8b_0  
openblas                  0.3.21          openmp_hf78f355_3    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1s               h1a28f6b_0  
packaging                 23.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.5.2           py310h46d7db6_0  
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh1a96a4e_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    9.3.0           py310hf4a492f_1  
pip                       22.3.1          py310hca03da5_0  
platformdirs              2.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.36             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h1a28f6b_0  
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.14.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9           py310hca03da5_0  
python                    3.10.9               hc0d8a6c_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.7          py310hca03da5_0  
pyzmq                     23.2.0          py310hc377ac9_0  
readline                  8.2                  h1a28f6b_0  
scikit-learn              1.2.0           py310h313beb8_0  
scipy                     1.9.3           py310h20cbe94_0  
seaborn                   0.12.2          py310hca03da5_0  
setuptools                65.6.3          py310hca03da5_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.40.1               h7a7dc30_0  
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0  
tk                        8.6.12               hb8d0fd4_0  
tornado                   6.2             py310h1a28f6b_0  
traitlets                 5.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.4.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.4.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2022g                h04d1e81_0  
wcwidth                   0.2.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
xz                        5.2.10               h80987f9_1  
zeromq                    4.3.4                hbdafb3b_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h5a0b063_0  
zstd                      1.5.2                h8574219_0
```

Comment: Using only 1 feature is weird. Are you sure you didn't mean `pca_features[:5000, :5]`? Other thought is that if the environment is `osx-64` (which means emulating on M1) and uses `mkl`, that would crash, since Rosetta doesn't emulate `x86_64` extensions. Showing us `conda list` for the environment might lead to insights. Also, try running the code in a REPL (i.e., `python` in the terminal) rather than Jupyter - you might recover additional error info.

Comment: @merv yes you are 100% right and thank you for pointing out that typo on my part. that line should read `pca_features[:5000, :5]` to select first six PCs

 ---- I updated the question to include `conda list` output for the virtual env I'm using. Hope it is helpful/useful. I did not see the `mkl` as an installed package

---- I will run the code again from the terminal and follow up with the results & any new information

Comment: Okay, yes not a MKL issue and you’re not emulating, since it shows **osxarm64**. However, you are mixing `defaults` channel packages with `conda-forge` ones and that can lead to library loading issues. I’d recommend sourcing everything from Conda Forge.  A `conda update --all -c conda-forge` might do the trick but it could change some package versions.

Comment: 1) ran code agin in REPL, same issue occured with the kernel crashing and unfortunately no additional error info
2) good to know can cross one potential issue off the board
3) Just ran `conda update --all -c conda-forge` Seeing the _channel_ column is almost entirely `conda-forge` minus a handful of packages. Thinking to re-run the code via the terminal or VScode and see if sourcing only from `conda-forge` resolves potential load issues (fingers crossed) with the libraries used ?

Comment: Ran my code after switch all package version to source from Conda Forge. Still getting the same unexpected kernel crash issue. Other fixes I have tried - step 7 in this [article](https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks-on-a-mac-m1/); updated my `eventsloop.py` file and even ran it specifically from jupyter notebook and no luck